# Difference between var and let

Tags: javascript, var, let

I just read the discussion about `var` and `let` in *Kyle Simpsons* "You Dont Know Javascript."

[Chapter 2: Nested Scopes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/up%20%26%20going/ch2.md#nested-scopes)

The function `foo` uses block declaration of variables with `let`, the function `bar` uses ordinary declaration with `var`. For my clarity, in this example, the variables `b` and `c` are actually available in the same scopes, correct? So what is the point of presenting the `foo` function here?

```
function foo() {
    var a = 1;
    if (a >= 1) {
        let b = 2;

        while (b < 5) {
            let c = b*2;
            b++;
            console.log(a + b); 
        }
    }   
}

function bar() {
    var a = 1;
    if (a >= 1) {
        var b = 2;

        while (b < 5) {
            var c = b*2;
            b++;
            console.log(a + b); 
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: The statement before the example says "Besides some nuanced details, the scoping rules will behave roughly the same as we just saw with functions:". Sounds like he's just repeating the example.

Comment: in `bar` b is available outside of if statement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between using "let" and "var" to declare a variable in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable-in-jav)

Comment: Not a duplicate, because I understand the difference. After reading the answers, I understand that my interpretation of `let` was to assume, that a variable is available only to the declaring scope and no inner scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `foo` function the `b` variable is not accessible outside of the `if` statement as well as the `c` variable is not accessible outside of the `while`.

The reason for this is that `let` declared variables are block scoped.

For example the following `log(b)` will result in `b is undefined`:

```
function foo() {
    var a = 1;
    if (a >= 1) {
        let b = 2;

        while (b < 5) {
            let c = b*2;
            b++;
            console.log(a + b); 
        }
    }   

    console.log(b); 
}
```

Comment: Ok, that is fine. I was kind of confused in the context of the text (inner / lower scope), where a variable declared with `let` still is available to the inner scope of the declaration scope. I was understanding `let` as declaring exclusively to the current scope and no inner scopes.

Answer (score 1):

`var` scope is the nearest `function` block, while `let` is only visible in the nearest pairs of `{...}`.

Thus, in `bar()` you could use `b` and `c` outside the `if` statement because they "belong" to the whole function.